# Update text on CCLabelTFF end in bad access?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I'm doing a little game in Coco2D and I have a countdown clock *Note: As I am just trying to fix a bug, I am not working on cleanup so the timer can stop, etc.*
Here is my code I'm using to setup the label and start the timer:

```
timer = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"10.0000" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20]; 
        timerDisplay = timer;
        timerDisplay.position = ccp(277,310);
        [self addChild:timerDisplay];
        timeLeft = 10;

        timerObject = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Note: timeLeft is a double

This is updateTimers's code:

```
 -(void)updateTimer {
         NSLog(@"Got Called!");

         timeLeft = timeLeft -0.1;
     [timer setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeLeft]];
       timerDisplay = timer;
         timerDisplay.position = ccp(277,310);
         [self removeChild:timerDisplay cleanup:YES];
         //[self addChild:timerDisplay];  
       if (timeLeft <= 0) {
             [timerObject invalidate];
         }     

     }
```

When I run this I toggle between crashing on this this:
`[timer setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeLeft]];`
 and in the green arrow thing it gives `Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)`
and
`0x197a7ff:  movl   16(%edi), %esi` and in the green arrow thing it gives `Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "timer" (not a very good name for a text object IMHO) is being auto-released because it was initialized with a convenience method. So when your timer fires it is likely attempting to manipulate a freed object. There are two ways to fix it: a. alloc and initialize the object yourself, or b. add a "retain" message to it such as:

```
[[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"10.0000" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20] retain];
```

In both cases you will then be responsible to release the object in your dealloc or similar method when you are done with it:

```
[timer release];
```

Comment: The name is good when you have 500 other objects in your game so you can simply state your thought...

Comment: I personally don't think so. I would call it timerText or something. I would only call an actual timer "timer". ;)

Comment: True but I had the label **before** the timer and it was hard coded into other place and it would be a pain to fix, anyways thanks for the help it works great now!

Comment: Just advice, take it or leave it. But that makes even less sense to me, if you had it before the timer, why wouldn't you have called it "label"? Anyways, glad you got it working.